# Installation profiles: add module/theme search path?

Tags: distributions

I'm trying to create a "base" installation profile with the modules and settings i need for every project which the specific project-profiles should derive from. It's no problem to run the install-part of my basic profile, but is there a way to use modules and themes that are stored in the 1st profiles folder?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to "inherit" that way between profiles. My team uses a small script that symlinks the modules directory from the base profiles into the modules dir of the subprofile, to solve this.

So the structure becomes

```
profiles/base-profile/modules
profiles/base-profile/modules/ctools
profiles/sub-profiles/modules/modules         <-- Symlink to base-profile/modules
profiles/sub-profiles/modules/modules/ctools  <-- From symlink
profiles/sub-profiles/modules/views
```